# Add new bitmap to ArrayList<Bitmap>

Tags: java, android, arraylist, bitmap

I have an ArrayList i would like to add a new bitmap to the list evertime a button is clicked.but when i check the size of the bitmap it is always one.my code is below please help.

```
      ArrayList<Bitmap> rev;

        findViewById(R.id.galleryb).setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
         @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
           Bitmap bmps = mTextureView.getBitmap();
                rev = new ArrayList<Bitmap>();
                for (int i = 0; i < 50; i++)
                {

                    rev.add(bmps[i]);
              Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),""+rev.size(),   Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                }
            }

     }
    });
```

Comment: Where do you check size and where do you handle the button click?

Comment: How does that compile? bmps is a `Bitmap`, not a `Bitmap[]`

Comment: Why are you using an index operation on Bitmap class

Comment: @Fildor i edited the answer and added the onclick callback.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are creating a new `ArrayList` again and again.

```
rev = new ArrayList<Bitmap>();
```

Keep this outside of `OnClickListener()`